# Set ng-click attribute value from a string variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I have an external JSON file which is a collection of buttons/actions like this

```
   {  
   "foo1":{  
      "name":"productDetails",
      "displayAs":"button",
      "action":"viewDetails()"
   },
   "foo2":{  
      "name":"sell",
      "displayAs":"button",
      "action":"sellProduct()"
   }
}
```

Later, in my view, I create a `<div>` using ng-repeat for each object contained in that JSON.

My question is, can I set the ng-click property as it it in the JSON file like this?

```
<li ng-repeat = "field in fields">
    <div ng-click = field.action > {{field.name}} </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Why don't you try and check if you can do it or not?

Comment: If you just use the function name in your json (like `action: 'viewDetails'`), ou could use `$scope[field.action]()` or `this[field.action]()`, depending on how your controller is organized, or use an if/else tree: `if (field.action === 'viewDetails()') $scope.viewDetails()`

Comment: Yes, you can, you'll have to change your data slightly though. Do as @DevDig has said. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lsqdcpa/)

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL I wouldn't post this if I didn't try it, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using `ng-bind-html`.

```
 <li ng-repeat = "field in fields">
    <div bind-html-compile ng-bind-html="trust(field)"  >  </div>
  </li>
```

Add `bind-html-compile` directive to compile the DOM so that changes will effect to DOM elements

Directive

```
 .directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
            }, function(value) {
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
 }]);
```

In `trust` function pass the object as an argument and return the html trust element

```
 $scope.trust = function(html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml('<div ng-click = "' + html.action + '" > {{field.name}} </div>');
 }
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$sce){

$scope.viewDetails = function(){console.log("viewDetails")}
$scope.sellProduct = function(){console.log("sellProduct")}
$scope.fields =    {  
   "foo1":{  
      "name":"productDetails",
      "displayAs":"button",
      "action":"viewDetails()" 
   },
   "foo2":{  
      "name":"sell",
      "displayAs":"button", 
      "action":"sellProduct()"
   }
}

$scope.trust = function(html){

return $sce.trustAsHtml('<div ng-click = "'+html.action+'" > {{field.name}} </div>');

}


}).directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <li ng-repeat = "field in fields">
    <div bind-html-compile ng-bind-html="trust(field)"  >  </div>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: why `ng-bind-html` has `trust(field)`, it has been designed to put `html` inside element..

Comment: Trust function return html so that ng bind html will bind that

Comment: I'd suggest to do simpler way [this commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978381/set-ng-click-attribute-value-from-a-string-variable/42978725?noredirect=1#comment73048734_42978381)